# Enviar comando ESC/POS a impresora EPSON TM-T20II desde consola de comandos de Windows

Tags: electron

estoy realizando una aplicación usando Electron y necesito abrir un cajón portamonedas que está conectado a la impresora a través de rj11 sin tener que imprimir nada.

Sé que se le puede enviar un comando a la impresora para que abra el cajón pero no doy la tecla.

En la imagen adjunta envío la información de EPSON de cuál es el comando que hay que enviarle a la cajonera pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Gracias de antemano!

[image: Información del fabricante - EPSON TM-T20II]

Answer (score 0):

esto te puede servir https://github.com/mayconbordin/printerguy a nivel de Electron parece que no es posiblepero si desde node.js

Comment: Muchas gracias, no había visto tu respuesta. Al final lo que he hecho es configurar en el ordenador una impresora que no imprime, solo abre el cajón. Entonces, desde electrón, como si se puede elegir la impresora a la que se manda, lo que hago es decirle que, cuando se lanza el evento que requiere abrir tan solo la cajonera, mando imprimir a esa impresora y así se abre la cajonera sin imprimir nada. Igualmente muchas gracias por el aporte.

Answer (score 0):

**POSIBLE SOLUCION:**

Bueno, sé que es un poco "chapuza" y que lo elegante sería haber dado con la solución a mi pregunta pero a salvo de algo mejor quizás esto ayude a alguien:

He creado dos impresoras:

```
#1.: Impresora normal, configurada para que imprima el ticket y además abra la cajonera.
#2.: Impresora cajonera, configurada para que no imprima el ticket pero sí abra la cajonera.
```

**Para configurarla de esta manera (en la TM-T20II) seguir los siguientes pasos:**

```
# En la pestaña de "Papel/Calidad"->Origen del papel => None
# Alimentación y corte->Preestablecido=>Docum. [Sin alument.,sin corte]. Además en Detallado asegurarse que no hay activo nada.
# Periféricos->Periféricos=>Caja. Configurar el cajón para que abra, a través de Caja #1 (2 pines), abrir, tanto al inicio del documento como al final del documento.
```

Además, si estás usando Electron, como es mi caso, puedes lanzar un evento que esté escuchando Electron de la siguiente manera:

```
const ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
ipcRenderer.send("abrirCajonera", nombreImpresoraCajonera);
```

Donde **nombreImpresoraCajonera** es el nombre de la impresora en el SO y abrirCajonera el método definido en Electron. Más info en https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer

En mi caso yo tengo una tabla de configuración en BBDD que contiene los nombres de las impresoras.

En fin, espero que sirva de ayuda para alguien.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

excelente.
Una consulta como se puede realizar para imprimir en la bandeja Matricial de algunos modelos ?  en el caso de tm-h5000ii solo la puedo instalar como generica, pero no me reconoce la otra bandeja matricial.

Muchas gracias